# YII2 -MongoDB query for filtering nested array data

Tags: mongodb, yii2

I'm  facing problem with filtering data from monogo db embedded collection to YII2 frame work.If any one knows please help.
I'm having Categories collection like below.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55cb2133b35be8b7de137462"),
    "category" : "Technology",
    "subCategory" : [
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "sub_category_name" : "test1"

        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "sub_category_name" : "test2"

        },
        {
            "_id" : 3,
            "sub_category_name" : "test3"

        },
        {
            "_id" : 4,
            "sub_category_name" : "test4"
        }
    ]
}
```

in that I want to fetch the data based on applying search condition on sub_Category.

expected result : I want to get value of ids 1 and 2 in sub category.

I have tried below method, but got all the sub categories.

Input : $id = [1,2];

```
 $query = new Query;
 $rows = $query->select([])
        ->from('category')
        ->where(array('_id' => '55c9caef8fae76a4a9d96c5a','subCategory._id' =>  $id));
  $rows = $query->all();
```

Anyone help on this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select everything there is no need to actually call `select`. As for the rest, I think I notice 2 issues.

First I don't think Yii2 does auto `MongoId` conversion, so you'll see if you actually get the document back as a whole with just the `_id` selection (I don't think it will). Secondly,  the name of the subdocument field seems wrong.

Here's what I think will help you further:

```
$query = (new Query)->from('category')
   ->where(array(
     '_id' => new \MongoId('55c9caef8fae76a4a9d96c5a'),
     'subCategory._id' => [1, 2]
));
$rows = $query->all();
```

`MongoDB` only matches if the type **and** the value match. 
This is why you probably need to convert your main `_id` to a `MongoId` and the `subCategory._id` need to be integers. In your example that should be fine, but `PHP` tends to end up with string valued variables after a couple of operations (especially if you obtained it via another database). So in that case an extra call to `intval()` might be needed for the subdocument query part.

Comment: sorry that my mistake its "subCategory._id" . But still i'm getting all the sub categories from your query. Also I have tried with $elemMatch but didn't get exact answer.

Comment: Contrary to what I believed it seems [the extension has no support for subdocuments at all](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/2492). You'll have to fall back on a regular query for this one I'm afraid.

Comment: I got my answer by using mongodb aggregate method in yii2 like    $collection->aggregate(
                    array('$match' => $filterCondition), array('$skip' => $offset), array('$limit' => intval($limit))
            );

Comment: You should add this as an answer and accept it. That way people in the future won't have to search.